# Location-based networking website for students

Tags: javascript, html, web, geolocation

I want to make a location-based academic website(bootstrap project ) where a said question will be visible only to those present in the pre-specified radius. I can code in HTML,CSS and currently learning JavaScript and PHP. Anyone willing to give me some pointers? (code resources, relevant templates or useful literature)

Comment: This seems like a big project. If you want to do this properly I recommend looking into php frameworks (symfony2 for example). In this example you can get the user's ip adress: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029757/how-do-i-get-the-user-ip-address-in-symfony2-controller and with the IP you can find their location. Once you have their location you can send back the corresponding view ( or a json if you are doing this via xmlhttprequest (ajax) ) containing the question's information.

Comment: I have a month(16 hours a day) to do this, hopefully it's enough.For front end, I am looking for a simple, free sourcecode template to reduce the overall work as functionality takes precedence. Thanks a lot, Grimbode.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the distances beteen locations using the [**Haversine**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula. The following  javascript functions are used to calculate the distance between the geolocated coordinates and that of the center location. Only if the distance is less than radius allow access.

```
function deg2rad(degrees){
radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
return radians;
}

function Haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  deltaLat = lat2 - lat1 ;
  deltaLon = lon2 - lon1 ;
  earthRadius = 3959; // in miles 6371 in meters.
  alpha    = deltaLat/2;
  beta     = deltaLon/2;
  a        = Math.sin(deg2rad(alpha)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(alpha)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(beta)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(beta)) ;
  c        = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  distance =  earthRadius * c;
  return distance.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you David for the detailed code.Really appreciate it.