# Symfony 4: How to pass the $_SERVER array as constructor argument

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, constructor, yaml

I am using [The DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) of Symfony 4 and I am trying to define the configuration settings (in `config/services.yml`) for creating a simple `ServerRequest` object. `ServerRequest` receives the `$_SERVER` variable (array) as argument for the constructor parameter `$serverParams`.

It should print the array, but, instead, it prints the string "$_SERVER":

> Hello from ServerRequest!
>
> *...path-to-project-root*/mytests/ServerRequest.php:14:string '$_SERVER'
>   (length=8)

Maybe you have an idea? Thank you very much!

---

#### config/services.yml:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    MyTests\ServerRequest:
        arguments:
            $serverParams: $_SERVER
```

#### mytests/ServerRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace MyTests;

class ServerRequest {

    private $serverParams;

    public function __construct($serverParams) {
        $this->serverParams = $serverParams;

        echo 'Hello from ServerRequest!<br/>';

        var_dump($this->serverParams);
    }

}
```

#### bootstrap.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

/*
 * Include the Composer autoloader.
 */
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
 * Create dependency injection container.
 */
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$fileLocator = new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/config');
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, $fileLocator);
$loader->load('services.yml');
$container->compile();

/*
 * Create ServerRequest instance.
 */
$serverRequest = $container->get(\MyTests\ServerRequest::class);
```

#### composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.0",
        "symfony/config": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^4.0",
        "symfony/process": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lock": "^4.0",
        "symfony/debug": "^4.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyTests\\": "mytests/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put a check in your constructor and if serverParams is null then set it to $_SERVER.  Might be better to make a server request factory though to keep your ServerRequest class itself free of globals.  Take a look at some of the many psr-7 libraries out there for examples or even the Symfony request/response objects.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @Cerad! It is a good one. Though, I already implemented it as you suggest. I just tried to simplify my example in my question. My factory receives an optional `$serverParams` array (at least), assigning `$_SERVER` if it's empty. That's then passed as argument to the factory method. But I found the task interesting, so I had to try it. With no luck though. Hence, I posted a question... Thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the php super globals in symfony as it makes your code non testable.

You should pass the environment vars to the parameters.yml and use it where it is necessary.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

If you need some of the data from the user request you should get the request stack service or use a symfony expression like in the following answer:

[How do I get the user IP address in Symfony2 controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029757/how-do-i-get-the-user-ip-address-in-symfony2-controller)

Comment: Thank you very much, Albert!